# command line smtp gmail not sending the email

Tags: email, ssl, cmd, smtp, gmail

Hey guys im trying to send and email using the command prompt.

Im using this command to contact gmail's server:

**openssl s_client -starttls smtp -connect smtp.gmail.com:587 -crlf -ign_eof**

Then i continue with contacting the server as shown in the picture.

The server allows me to enter the **DATA** but not to put **.** to end it.

[image: What i did]

If someone can help me fix this i will really appreciate it.

I blanked stuff to protect my privacy / account

Comment: It might help to post code instead of a image. Also, make up something for every instance you want to keep private, but keep it the same across the whole post, so your email would be example@example.com _everywhere_ in the post, wherever your email was.

Comment: I thought Q on its own line closes the connection

Comment: @alldani the question is why '.' doesnt work and i cant put example@example.com cause the server wont allow it and wont let me continue

Comment: What server? I'm talking about the post here.

Comment: @alldani what you see in the picture is my connection with the gmail server

Comment: @RobertMoskal  its QUIT that closes and not in the text area